# Enabling menu icons in Gnome3

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, gnome3, eclipse

When I start Thunderbird or the IDE 'Eclipse', there are no icons in the menu entries. Several solutions found on the Internet suggest things like setting a specific dconf-value, but with my installation (Arch) this is not possible:

```
% gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface menus-have-icons true
No such key 'menus-have-icons'
```

So what is the current way for enabling these icons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that since GTK 3.10 the value 'menus-have-icons' is [deprecated](http://igurublog.wordpress.com/2014/03/22/gtk-3-10-drops-menu-icons-and-mnemonics/). I found a [solution](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?p=1680581#post1680581) by using this command:

```
% gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>}"
```

Comment: as gsettings or gnome-tweak-tool will overwrite the key, if you want to disable middle click paste you should not disable it via gnome-tweak-tool, instead you should use this style: `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "{'Gtk/ButtonImages': <1>, 'Gtk/MenuImages': <1>,'Gtk/EnablePrimaryPaste': <0>}"`

Comment: thx Stephan, this works for me on archlinux!

Answer (score 1):

For those who miss icons in GTK2 or GTK3 applications, but not on GNOME (e.g. KDE + pidgin), one of the easy options is to use `lxappearance`: on the "Other" tab it has "Show images on buttons" and "Show images in menus" checkboxes, toggling which you can toggle these settings on the fly.